# Jquery document on click using :not?

Tags: jquery, document

I have a div (that contains navigation links) that I'm trying to close if a user clicks away from it. My code works fine except on iPads it effectively stops the links from working because I'm using document as the trigger.  I need to exclude the div (#menu_container) from this action but I just can't seem to get it to work. I've tried using :not but despite spending a couple of hours Googling the problem nothing seems to quite do the trick.  I must be missing something really obvious here?! Here's my code without any attempt at using :not:

```
$(document).on('click touchstart', function (){
    jQuery("#menu_container div").hide($);
});
```

And this was one of the many attempts that failed:

```
$(document).not("#menu_container div").click( function(){
    jQuery("#menu_container div").hide($);
});
```

Comment: .not doesn't work that way. It simply reduces the selection based on the passed in selector. In this case, your selection is `document`, so .not has no effect.

Comment: `jQuery("#menu_container div").hide($);`?? Why are you passing a reference to the jQuery function into `hide`? For that matter, why are you using `$` in some places and `jQuery` in others? Consistency is useful.

Comment: Separately, in your first function, `this` will be `document` in your event handler, so the `.not(this)` part of `jQuery("#menu a").not(this).removeClass();` doesn't have any effect either. What are you expecting `this` will be?

Comment: You can disregard the removeClass line if you like. It's simply targeting a top level of navigation and I shouldn't have included it in this post. It works though! As far as the mixture of $ and jQuery is concerned you're right... I should re-write it to be consistent.  It's for a Wordpress project so some of my code relates to Safe Mode and some doesn't.  I have all the code wrapped in a function that ensures it works.  The point is that this code works, except I need to stop it from triggering if a click is registered from within the #menu_container div. I can't work out how to do that?

Comment: Read this: [event.target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

Comment: Ur div id is menu_container rt ? So just use that.. `$(document).not('#menu_container').click()`

Comment: Alternatively u can do this.. `$(document).on('click', function(e) { if (e.target.id === 'menu_container' ) return ; else { // do ur stuff } );`

Comment: The above solution won't work if u click on children of `menu_container`

Comment: alternatively you could just give the selected link a class of selected, then just filter on the class that you added, and remove all other instances of that class

Comment: I've edited to remove some of the irrelevant code.  Basically the first piece of code in my post works fine except in iPads it renders links within the #menu_container useless because clicking on them just closes the div. I want users to be able to close the menu by clicking away from it but I can't work out how to do it.  I thought using :not might be the solution, but perhaps not (pardon the pun)?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `find() & addBack()` but be careful with this as this will be expensive if you have too many elements inside your div.

```
var excludedItems = $('#menu_container').find('*').addBack();
$(document).not(excludedItems).on('click', function(){ // handle event });
```

Comment: Thank you for this code Arkantos but I couldn't get it to work.  There are lots of links within the div #menu_container so even if it did, it might not be a good solution.